# Removing unnessary classes from third party libraries and JARs

Tags: java, class, jar, dependencies, proguard

I need to remove unused classes from third party JARs. Why tools should I use?

I already tried to use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net). However, it removes only unused classes from the project itself but the library jars - third party - always remain unchanged.

Comment: Why do you want to remove classes from the 3rd party jars ?

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, because - thanks to [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) - there's no way to really know which classes are unused and which are not, especially when it comes to third-party JARs (i.e. you have no idea of how they work internally).

Comment: +Joonas Thanks for your answer. You are right, but [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) can handle reflection and introspection. So, is there any other tool that can do the same with third party Jars??

Comment: @M.ES: ProGuard can handle simple cases of reflection, but its [manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/introduction.html) explicitly warns about the general case: *It is generally impossible to foresee which classes have to be preserved (with their original names), since the class names might be read from a configuration file, for instance. You therefore have to specify them in your ProGuard configuration, with the same simple -keep options.*

Comment: Have you tried extracting the classes from the library jars and running proguard on them as if they are part of the main project?  Or can ProGuard only remove unused classes that have source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an uber jar and then use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).  Repackaging library classes into jars would be a challenge, but from the spirit of your question you will prefer the uber jar as such.

As other posters have commented, you still need to be careful about classes loaded through the so much abused and misunderstood reflection mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

@Joonas Pulakka is right. But if you still really want to do this and be sure that your application will not fail for `ClassNotFoundException` run your application with option -verbose:class, perform all usecases that exist, take the log that contains all loaded classes. Then take list of all classes of your third party library and file all classes from your library that have been never loaded. Then create alternative jar file that contains only "needed" classes and pray :)

Good luck.

Comment: +AlexR Lool, I am talking about 35.7 MB of JARs.

Comment: most important: the praying phase :))

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing to know what classes and libraries you are using, and even if there is risk (as pointed out by Peter) to removing unused stuff, there is cost in carrying any kind of excess baggage, and you shouldn't just keep accumulating. If you use reflection, then get a handle on what you are using it for, and systematically get rid of what you don't need. There are benefits to a leaner code-base that you understand better.

Answer (score -7):

Java only loads class as they are used.  Removing classes can only cause you problems and won't help you at runtime.  36 MB of code isn't that much given only a portion of it will be loaded.  How much memory do you have? Most PC have at least 2000 MB these days  If you are downloading your applet or Java WebStart application over a slow link I would imagine you are using pack200 (to make the jars smaller) and have included the minimum of libraries already.

Comment: +Lawrey Thanks for your answer and I understand your point of view. However, the requirements are to eliminate unused classes from JARs and to put all Jars into a single FAT JAR. I know it can be useless but they only want it cleaner.

Comment: You can put them all into a single JAR now. You should make them aware that this could make the application unstable and unsupportable. i.e. When, not if, it breaks you have at least warned them it was a bad idea.  You don't want them blaming your for not doing your job when what they are asking is unreasonable.

Comment: +Lawrey I'll do it. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: At the end of the day, you have to what is asked.  But you should also be ready to make them aware of the consequences of what they ask for. ;)

Comment: You might not be aware of some reasons this is actually really necessary.  I was just trying to use Goldman Sachs collections in an Android project and it would cause Eclipse to hang when I was trying to launch my app, because that library is HUGE (e.g. containing a unique map implementation for each combination of primitive types).  The ADT can't pick and choose the classes it needs because it "dexes" the libraries into the Dalvik VM's special bytecode format.  So if I can't find a tool to get rid of the unecessary classes, I just can't use that library.

Comment: @Andy Are you saying Android loads classes eagerly, before they are needed?  That sounds like a strange choice given the server version of HotSpot doesn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey no, I wasn't saying anything about what happens when Android's Dalvik VM is running.  I'm saying that it appears Android Development Toolkit converts every class in jars in the project's libs folder into Dalvik VM's dex format, and that this process seemed to be unworkably memory/processor intensive when it was trying to convert the GS Collections library.  I suspect it is not performing a simple bytecode translation on the library, which I would think takes little memory, but rather building an entire abstract syntax tree out of the classes in the jar to perform the conversion.

Comment: @Andy While expensive, you shouldn't need to do this on a regular basis.