# Java: Compile only selected methods from another class

Tags: java, oop, jar, build, compilation

If my java class "UserClass" depends on another class "UsedClass"(provided as a library jar). If the "UsedClass" has 26 methods(lets say A - Z). But my "UserClass" needs only methods from(lets say A to D, assuming they dont internally call any methods other than A to D). When I build the "UserClass", Is there any way to prevent unused methods(example E to Z) from "UsedClass" from being shipped in my application(which may increase size of distributable/memory consumption while execution).

Comment: If UsedClass has 26 methods, I would first look, if UsedClass does too much/ has more than one responsibility. If that is the case I would refactor each responsibility in its own class - say in classA and classB - if that is possible. ClassB could still utilize classA.A-Z per object composition.

Comment: 26 was just arbitrary number(Could be much less). UsedClass is assumed to be developed by someone else(used as a library jar lets say). In that case do all unused methods also ship with the app ? Is there a way to avoid this.

Comment: if its an external library - you may be out of luck. But maybe some one does know some trick. If you know the person who writes this library and you see that the class does indeed has more than one responsibility - maybe you could talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do premature optimisation,  in most cases it is the libraries who adding size to your project. If your methods not used any there then just delete then.  If the are used by some other unrelated code then you better split your code into modules so you can use them in a different combination. As I already said your code(the code you created) will be the smallest part of your final application. 
If you still insist that you want to conditionally compile methods, then I will say it isn't possible with standard tools.

Comment: Hi, all my code methods will be used, its the external library jar files unused methods that I am mainly concerned about, as they may be adding size to my application.

Comment: Then you probably looking to get rid of unused classes furst. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7384970/4517895